# geopandas shapefile wkt column not visible

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile, writetofile, wkt

I have a dataset like the image below. I want to save it as shp file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnBsZ.png)

I tried with this code.

```
df['geometry'] = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['geometry'])
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
gdf = gdf.set_crs('epsg:4326')
gdf.to_file("filename.shp", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

When I open the data in arcgis pro, wkt (location information) does not appear in the table. how can i fix this?

Edit: It is not visible in arcgis pro because the coordinate system is not defined. I solved the problem by defining the coordinate system in Arcgis Pro.